# Looping through files with spaces in the names?

Tags: bash, scripting, text-processing, find, filenames

I wrote the following script to diff the outputs of two directores with all the same files in them as such:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in `find . -name "*.csv"`  
do
     echo "file = $file";
     diff $file /some/other/path/$file;
     read char;
done
```

I know there are other ways to achieve this.  Curiously though, this script fails when the files have spaces in them.  How can I deal with this?

Example output of find:

```
./zQuery - abc - Do Not Prompt for Date.csv
```

Comment: I disagree with that this would be a duplicate. The accepted answer answers how to loop over filenames with spaces; that has nothing to do with "why is looping over find's output bad practise". I found this question (not the other) because I need to loop over filenames with spaces, as in: for file in $LIST_OF_FILES; do ...  where $LIST_OF_FILES is not the output of find; it's just a list of filenames (separated by newlines).

Comment: @CarloWood - file names can include newlines, so your question is rather unique: looping over a list of filenames that can contain spaces but not newlines.  I think you're going to have to use the IFS technique, to indicate that the break occurs at '\n'

Comment: @Diagon- woah, I never realized that file names are allowed to contain newlines. I use mostly (only) linux/UNIX and there even spaces are rare; I certainly never in my entire life saw newlines being used :p. They might as well forbid that imho.

Comment: @CarloWood - filenames end in a null ('\0', same as '').  Anything else is acceptable.

Comment: @CarloWood You have to remember that people vote first and read second...

Comment: Oops! Just now, I would like to add my answer below, but I see that this question has been (mis-)closed. I am working on a similar problem as the OP and found a solution wanna share. My suggested approach involves rewriting the script **without using `find` and `for`**. That's why I mentioned that this is not a duplicate question. I cannot use the solutions provided below because I am adhering to POSIX, which means no `read -d`, and I am sourcing a file in the script, which means no spawning a subshell. Using `find` does not meet my requirements, as `find` cannot take `find . -name '*/*.csv'`.

Comment: `find` is not usable when it comes to `*/*`. `for` is a pain in axxhxxx when the string contains `$IFS`. I forgo them both. It is important to understand where and how globbing occurs. Consider why `$ ls */*.csv` works in the shell. Globbing occurs **right at the place where it is unquoted**. `$ ls */*.csv` becomes `$ ls 'dir name/file one.csv' 'dir name/file two.csv' 'dir name/file three.csv'`. `ls` takes **three arguments**, with spaces, without any problems. `for` kinda overdo things, smashes this array of three arguments into one plain string, then re-splits it with `$IFS`. Very bad.

Comment: My solution: `fname_pattern='*/*.csv' ; process() { while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do echo "file = $1" ; diff "$1" "/some/other/path/$1" ; read -r _ ; shift ; done ; } ; process $fname_pattern`. Rewrite using a function. Call the function `process` with unquoted variable which let the globbing occurs. The function takes an array of (whatever number of) elements. Using `while ... shift` to process each element. Benefits: (1) No subshell, allows source files in my case; (2) Won't break for any weird characters; (3) Allows `/` in the pattern, which is not possible by `find`.

Comment: Benefit (4) POSIX compliant, as no `read -d`. Remark: If one wants to match pattern `*/with   3 spaces*.csv`, one should properly quote it, `fname_pattern="*/'with   3 spaces'*.csv"`.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

**Short answer (closest to your answer, but handles spaces)**

```
OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'
for file in `find . -type f -name "*.csv"`  
do
     echo "file = $file"
     diff "$file" "/some/other/path/$file"
     read line
done
IFS="$OIFS"
```

**Better answer (also handles wildcards and newlines in file names)**

```
find . -type f -name "*.csv" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    echo "file = $file"
    diff "$file" "/some/other/path/$file"
    read line </dev/tty
done
```

**Best answer (based on [Gilles' answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names/9500#9500))**

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec sh -c '
  file="$0"
  echo "$file"
  diff "$file" "/some/other/path/$file"
  read line </dev/tty
' exec-sh {} ';'
```

Or even better, to avoid running one `sh` per file:

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    echo "$file"
    diff "$file" "/some/other/path/$file"
    read line </dev/tty
  done
' exec-sh {} +
```

---

**Long answer**

You have three problems:

1. By default, the shell splits the output of a command on spaces, tabs, and newlines
2. Filenames could contain wildcard characters which would get expanded
3. What if there is a directory whose name ends in `*.csv`?

**1. Splitting only on newlines**

To figure out what to set `file` to, the shell has to take the output of `find` and interpret it somehow, otherwise `file` would just be the entire output of `find`.

The shell reads the `IFS` variable, which is set to `<space><tab><newline>` by default.

Then it looks at each character in the output of `find`.  As soon as it sees any character that's in `IFS`, it thinks that marks the end of the file name, so it sets `file` to whatever characters it saw until now and runs the loop.  Then it starts where it left off to get the next file name, and runs the next loop, etc., until it reaches the end of output.

So it's effectively doing this:

```
for file in "zquery" "-" "abc" ...
```

To tell it to only split the input on newlines, you need to do

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

before your `for ... find` command.

That sets `IFS` to a single newline, so it only splits on newlines, and not spaces and tabs as well.

If you are using `sh` or `dash` instead of `ksh93`, `bash` or `zsh`, you need to write `IFS=$'\n'` like this instead:

```
IFS='
'
```

That is probably enough to get your script working, but if you're interested to handle some other corner cases properly, read on...

**2. Expanding `$file` without wildcards**

Inside the loop where you do

```
diff $file /some/other/path/$file
```

the shell tries to expand `$file` (again!).

It could contain spaces, but since we already set `IFS` above, that won't be a problem here.

But it could also contain wildcard characters such as `*` or `?`, which would lead to unpredictable behavior.  (Thanks to Gilles for pointing this out.)

To tell the shell not to expand wildcard characters, put the variable inside double quotes, e.g.

```
diff "$file" "/some/other/path/$file"
```

The same problem could also bite us in

```
for file in `find . -name "*.csv"`
```

For example, if you had these three files

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
*.csv
```

(very unlikely, but still possible)

It would be as if you had run

```
for file in file1.csv file2.csv *.csv
```

which will get expanded to

```
for file in file1.csv file2.csv *.csv file1.csv file2.csv
```

causing `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` to be processed twice.

Instead, we have to do

```
find . -name "*.csv" -print | while IFS= read -r file; do
    echo "file = $file"
    diff "$file" "/some/other/path/$file"
    read line </dev/tty
done
```

`read` reads lines from standard input, splits the line into words according to `IFS` and stores them in the variable names that you specify.

Here, we're telling it not to split the line into words, and to store the line in `$file`.

Also note that `read line` has changed to `read line </dev/tty`.

This is because inside the loop, standard input is coming from `find` via the pipeline.

If we just did `read`, it would be consuming part or all of a file name, and some files would be skipped.

`/dev/tty` is the terminal where the user is running the script from.  Note that this will cause an error if the script is run via cron, but I assume this is not important in this case.

Then, what if a file name contains newlines?

We can handle that by changing `-print` to `-print0` and using `read -d ''` on the end of a pipeline:

```
find . -name "*.csv" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    echo "file = $file"
    diff "$file" "/some/other/path/$file"
    read char </dev/tty
done
```

This makes `find` put a null byte at the end of each file name.  Null bytes are the only characters not allowed in file names, so this should handle all possible file names, no matter how weird.

To get the file name on the other side, we use `IFS= read -r -d ''`.

Where we used `read` above, we used the default line delimiter of newline, but now, `find` is using null as the line delimiter. In `bash`, you can't pass a NUL character in an argument to a command (even builtin ones), but `bash` understands `-d ''` as meaning *NUL delimited*. So we use `-d ''` to make `read` use the same line delimiter as `find`. Note that `-d $'\0'`, incidentally, works as well, because `bash` not supporting NUL bytes treats it as the empty string.

To be correct, we also add `-r`, which says don't handle backslashes in file names specially.  For example, without `-r`, `\<newline>` are removed, and `\n` is converted into `n`.

A more portable way of writing this that doesn't require `bash` or `zsh` or remembering all the above rules about null bytes (again, thanks to Gilles):

```
find . -name '*.csv' -exec sh -c '
  file="$0"
  echo "$file"
  diff "$file" "/some/other/path/$file"
  read char </dev/tty
' exec-sh {} ';'
```

**3. Skipping directories whose names end in *.csv**

```
find . -name "*.csv"
```

will also match directories that are called `something.csv`.

To avoid this, add `-type f` to the `find` command.

```
find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec sh -c '
  file="$0"
  echo "$file"
  diff "$file" "/some/other/path/$file"
  read line </dev/tty
' exec-sh {} ';'
```

As [glenn jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman) points out, in both of these examples, the commands to execute for each file are being run in a subshell, so if you change any variables inside the loop, they will be forgotten.

If you need to set variables and have them still set at the end of the loop, you can rewrite it to use process substitution like this:

```
i=0
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    echo "file = $file"
    diff "$file" "/some/other/path/$file"
    read line </dev/tty
    i=$((i+1))
done < <(find . -type f -name '*.csv' -print0)
echo "$i files processed"
```

Note that if you try copying and pasting this at the command line, `read line` will consume the `echo "$i files processed"`, so that command won't get run.

To avoid this, you could remove `read line </dev/tty` and send the result to a pager like `less`.

---

**NOTES**

I removed the semi-colons (`;`) inside the loop.  You can put them back if you want, but they are not needed.

These days, `$(command)` is more common than `` `command` ``.  This is mainly because it's easier to write `$(command1 $(command2))` than ``` `command1 \`command2\`` ```.

`read char` doesn't really read a character.  It reads a whole line so I changed it to `read line`.

Comment: putting `while` in a pipeline can create issues with the subshell created (variables in the loop block not visible after the command completes for example). With bash, I would use input redirection and process substitution: `while read -r -d $'\0' file; do ...; done < <(find ... -print0)`

Comment: Sure, or using a heredoc: `while read; do; done <<EOF "$(find)" EOF`.  Not so easy to read however.

Comment: @glenn jackman: I tried to add more explanation just now.  Did I just make it better or worse?

Comment: You don't need `IFS, -print0, while` and `read` if you handle `find` to its full, as shown below in my solution.

Comment: Your first solution will cope with any character except newline if you also turn off globbing with `set -f`.

Comment: Yes, but then we'd have to restore it at the end of the loop.  The first solution was intended to be simple, so I'm reluctant to change it.  Now you made this comment, at least it's on record. Thanks. :-)

Comment: tldr; `IFS=$'\n'`

Comment: Thank you very much for `IFS=$'\n'` - this was crazy, handling a single file list (from file) with spaces in filenames in for/while was nearly impossible without it...

Comment: the "best" answer is relative, and i would say whatever is most understandable/maintainable by the scripter.  for me, that is a slight modification to the first one.  rather than saving/restoring IFS, you can use a subshell: ``(IFS=$'\n'; for file in ... )``

Comment: May I ask why not just temperately setting `$IFS=''` to empty string and let the unquoted `$pattern` expands? `pattern='*.csv' ; old_IFS=${IFS} ; IFS='' ; for f in ${pattern} ; do IFS=${old_IFS:-"${IFS}"} ; unset old_IFS ; : play around here ; done`. I have tested (1) it works  with dir and fname with spaces, (2) it works with globbing in both dir and fname, (3) works with dir and fname with globbing characters `*` too. It is kind of _too good to be true_. Are there any bugs that I have overlook? @Jayen - In my case I cannot do it in a sub-shell.

Answer (score 26):

This script fails if any file name contains spaces or shell globbing characters `\[?*`. The `find` command outputs one file name per line. Then the command substitution `` `find …` `` is evaluated by the shell as follows:

1. Execute the `find` command, grab its output.
2. Split the `find` output into separate words. Any whitespace character is a word separator.
3. For each word, if it is a globbing pattern, expand it to the list of files it matches.

For example, suppose there are three files in the current directory, called `` `foo* bar.csv ``, `foo 1.txt` and `foo 2.txt`.

1. The `find` command returns `./foo* bar.csv`.
2. The shell splits this string at the space, producing two words: `./foo*` and `bar.csv`.
3. Since `./foo*` contains a globbing metacharacter, it's expanded to the list of matching files: `./foo 1.txt` and `./foo 2.txt`.
4. Therefore the `for` loop is executed successively with `./foo 1.txt`, `./foo 2.txt` and `bar.csv`.

You can avoid most problems at this stage by toning down word splitting and turning off globbing. To tone down word splitting, set the `IFS` variable to a single newline character; this way the output of `find` will only be split at newlines and spaces will remain. To turn off globbing, run `set -f`. Then this part of the code will work as long as no file name contains a newline character.

```
IFS='
'
set -f
for file in $(find . -name "*.csv"); do …
```

(This isn't part of your problem, but I recommend using `$(…)` over `` `…` ``. They have the same meaning, but the backquote version has weird quoting rules.)

There's another problem below: `diff $file /some/other/path/$file` should be

```
diff "$file" "/some/other/path/$file"
```

Otherwise, the value of `$file` is split into words and the words are treated as glob patterns, like with the command substitutio above. If you must remember one thing about shell programming, remember this: **always use double quotes around variable expansions (`$foo`) and command substitutions (`$(bar)`)**, unless you know you want to split. (Above, we knew we wanted to split the `find` output into lines.)

A reliable way of calling `find` is telling it to run a command for each file it finds:

```
find . -name '*.csv' -exec sh -c '
  echo "$0"
  diff "$0" "/some/other/path/$0"
' {} ';'
```

In this case, another approach is to compare the two directories, though you have to explicitly exclude all the “boring” files.

```
diff -r -x '*.txt' -x '*.ods' -x '*.pdf' … . /some/other/path
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about wildcards as another reason to quote properly.  Thanks!  :-)

Comment: instead of `find -exec sh -c 'cmd 1; cmd 2' ";"`, you should use `find -exec cmd 1 {} ";" -exec cmd 2 {} ";"`, because the shell needs to mask the parameters, but find doesn't. In the special case here, echo "$0" doesn't need to be a part of the script, just append -print after the `';'`. You didn't include a question to proceed, but even that can be done by find, as shown below in my soulution. ;)

Comment: @userunknown: The use of `{}` as a substring of a parameter in `find -exec` is not portable, that's why the shell is needed. I don't understand what you mean by “the shell needs to mask the parameters”; if it's about quoting, my solution is properly quoted. You're right that the `echo` part could be performed by `-print` instead. `-okdir` is a fairly recent GNU find extension, it's not available everywhere. I didn't include the wait to proceed because I consider that extremely poor UI and the asker can easily put `read` in the shell snippet if he wants.

Comment: Quoting is a form of masking, isn't it? I don't understand your remark about what is portable, and what not. Your example (2nd from bottom) uses -exec to invoke `sh` and uses `{}` - so where is my example (beside -okdir) less portable? `find . -name "*.csv" -exec diff {} /some/other/path/{} ";" -print `

Comment: “Masking” isn't common terminology in shell literature, so you'll have to explain what you mean if you want to be understood. My example uses `{}` only once and in a separate argument; other cases (used twice or as a substring) are not portable. “Portable” means that it'll work on all unix systems; a good guideline is the [POSIX/Single Unix specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html).

Comment: May I ask why not just temperately setting `$IFS=''` to empty string and let the unquoted `$pattern` expands? `pattern='*.csv' ; old_IFS=${IFS} ; IFS='' ; for f in ${pattern} ; do IFS=${old_IFS:-"${IFS}"} ; unset old_IFS ; : play around here ; done`. I have tested (1) it works with dir and fname with spaces, (2) it works with globbing in both dir and fname, (3) works with dir and fname with globbing characters `*` too. Is there any bug that I have overlook?

Comment: @midnite If you have a pattern in a variable, you don't need to do anything with IFS: `pattern='*.csv'; for f in $pattern; do process -- "$f"; done` works fine. But that's not related to the question which is about `find` output.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - If `pattern='my file *.csv' contains spaces, we need to unset IFS. OP question is to loop through all `*.csv` files with spaces. OP attempted to solve it by using `find`, but I do not think `find` is doing any good here. It makes things more complicated which is not necessary.

Comment: @midnite If you want to have spaces inside the pattern, the natural way to do it is `pattern='my\ file\ *.csv`. The value of `pattern` here is a space (more generally IFS) separated list. You can avoid quoting all non-wildcard characters by unsetting IFS, but that just makes using the variable more complicated. But anyway, none of that helps with the question which is about generating a list of files with `find`. `find` is recursive and allows more ways to select files. The shell pattern `*.csv` is only equivalent in the special case when there are no subdirectories containing `.csv` files.

Comment: Thanks @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' - You gave a very good point that `find` will get files in subdirectories also. I need to glob expand and loop through file names with spaces also. I just find the solution is very simple: `IFS=''` and _unquote_. It is kind of "too good to be true", as others are using `find`, `arrays`, etc. My code is further illustrated here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/766527/150246 . Are there any faults or bugs that I have overlook?

Answer (score 22):

I'm surprised to not see `readarray` mentioned.  It makes this very easy when used in combination with the `<<<` operator:

```
$ touch oneword "two words"

$ readarray -t files <<<"$(ls)"

$ for file in "${files[@]}"; do echo "|$file|"; done
|oneword|
|two words|
```

Using the `<<<"$expansion"` construct also allows you to split variables containing newlines into arrays, like:

```
$ string=$(dmesg)
$ readarray -t lines <<<"$string"
$ echo "${lines[0]}"
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

`readarray` has been in Bash for years now, so this should probably be the canonical way to do this in Bash.

Comment: OMG.  TI've been looking for something like this to deal with spaces in file names forever!

Answer (score 8):

I'm surprised nobody mentioned the obvious `zsh` solution here yet:

```
for file (**/*.csv(ND.)) {
  do-something-with $file
}
```

(`(D)` to also include hidden files, `(N)` to avoid the error if there's no match, `(.)` to restrict to *regular* files.)

`bash4.3` and above now supports it partially as well:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob
for file in **/*.csv; do
  [ -f "$file" ] || continue
  [ -L "$file" ] && continue
  do-something-with "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 7):

Afaik find has all you need.

```
find . -okdir diff {} /some/other/path/{} ";"
```

find takes itself care for calling the programs savely. -okdir will prompt you before the diff (are you sure yes/no).

No shell involved, no globbing, jokers, pi, pa, po.

As a sidenote: If you combine find with for/while/do/xargs, in most cases, you're doing it wrong. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Why are you doing it wrong if you combine find with for/while/do/xargs?

Comment: Find already iterates over a subset of files. Most people who show up with questions could just use one of the actions (-ok(dir) -exec(dir), -delete) in combination wiht ";" or + (later for parallel invocation). The main reason to do so, is, that you don't have to fiddle around with file parameters, masking them for the shell. Not that important: You needn't new processes all the time, less memory, more speed. shorter program.

Comment: Not here to crush your spirit, but compare: `time find -type f -exec cat "{}" \;` with `time find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I stuff cat stuff`. The `xargs` version was faster by 11 seconds when processing 10000 empty files. Be careful when asserting that in most cases combining `find` with other utilities is wrong. `-print0` and `-0` are there to deal with spaces in the file names by using a zero byte as the item separator rather than a space.

Comment: @JonathanKomar: Your find/exec commando took 11.7 s on my system with 10.000 files, the xargs version 9.7 s,  `time find -type f -exec cat {} +` as suggested in my previous comment took 0.1 s. Note the subtile difference between "it is wrong" and "you're doing it wrong", especially when decorated with a smilie. Did you, for instance, do it wrong? ;) BTW, spaces in the filename are no problem for the above command and find in general. Cargo cult programmer? And by the way, combining find with other tools is fine, just xargs is most of the time superflous.

Comment: @userunknown I explained how my code deals with spaces for posterity (education of future viewers), and was not implying that your code does not. The `+` for parallel calls is very fast, as you mentioned. I would not say cargo cult programmer, because this ability to use `xargs` in this way comes in handy on numerous occasions. I agree more with the Unix philosophy: do one thing and do it well (use programs separately or in combination to get a job done). `find` is walking a fine line there.

Answer (score 6):

Loop through any files (*any* special character included) with the [completely safe find](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh) (see the link for documentation):

```
exec 9< <( find "$absolute_dir_path" -type f -print0 )
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    file_path="$(readlink -fn -- "$REPLY"; echo x)"
    file_path="${file_path%x}"
    echo "START${file_path}END"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `-d ''`.  I didn't realize that `$'\0'` was the same as `''`, but it seems to be.  Good solution, as well.

Comment: I like the decoupling of find and while, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

File names with spaces in them look like multiple names on the command line if they're not quoted. If your file is named "Hello World.txt", the diff line expands to:

```
diff Hello World.txt /some/other/path/Hello World.txt
```

which looks like four file names. Just put quotes around the arguments:

```
diff "$file" "/some/other/path/$file"
```

Comment: This helps but it doesn't solve my problem.  I still see cases where the file is being split up into multiple tokens.

Comment: This answer is misleading. The problem is the `for file in \`find . -name "*.csv"\`` command. If there is a file called `Hello World.csv`, `file` will be set to `./Hello` and then to `World.csv`. Quoting `$file` won't help.

Answer (score 1):

Double quoting is your friend.

```
diff "$file" "/some/other/path/$file"
```

Otherwise the variable's contents get word-split.

Comment: This is misleading. The problem is the `for file in \`find . -name "*.csv"\`` command. If there is a file called `Hello World.csv`, `file` will be set to `./Hello` and then to `World.csv`. Quoting `$file` won't help.

Answer (score 1):

With bash4, you can also use the builtin mapfile function to set an array containing each lines and iterate on this array.

```
$ tree 
.
├── a
│   ├── a 1
│   └── a 2
├── b
│   ├── b 1
│   └── b 2
└── c
    ├── c 1
    └── c 2

3 directories, 6 files
$ mapfile -t files < <(find -type f)
$ for file in "${files[@]}"; do
> echo "file: $file"
> done
file: ./a/a 2
file: ./a/a 1
file: ./b/b 2
file: ./b/b 1
file: ./c/c 2
file: ./c/c 1
```