# The best way to expand glob pattern?

Tags: bash, wildcards

I need to expand a glob pattern (like `../smth*/*`, or `/etc/cron*/`) into a list of files, programmatically. What would be the best way to do it?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special, just don't quote the `*`.

Comment: Though if you're going to be trying to parse it, use an array like the answer says.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Just let it expand inside an array declaration's right side:

```bash
list=(../smth*/)          # grab the list
echo "${#list[@]}"        # print array length
echo "${list[@]}"         # print array elements
for file in "${list[@]}"; do echo "$file"; done  # loop over the array
```

Note that the shell option `nullglob` needs to be set.
**It is not set by default.**
It causes globs with no match to expand to nothing instead of causing an error (in `zsh` or `bash -O failglob`) or be passed literally (all other Bourne-like shells).

Set it in `bash` with

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

or in `zsh` or `yash` with

```
set -o nullglob
```

though in `zsh` (where the `nullglob` initially came from), you'd rather use the `(N)` glob qualifier to avoid having to change a global setting:

```
list( ../smth*/(N) )
```

The ksh93 equivalent:

```
list=( ~(N)../smth*/ )
```

Comment: And how do I print that list afterwards?

Comment: It is just a regular array. You can do whatever you can with any array. Added some examples.

Comment: There is a problem. If pattern matches no files, it prints itself - which is not very good.

Comment: Ah, shopt -s nullglob solves it.

Comment: How do I undo `setopt` in zsh?

Comment: @lindhe, `unsetopt` and the same parameter as used for `setopt`.

Comment: Having the pattern print itself is probably what is wanted in some cases. Using the option `failglob` might be more appropriate in others. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/204944/85414) for an in-depth discussion.

Answer (score 8):

`compgen` is a Bash built-in that you can pass an escaped(!) pattern to, and it outputs matches, returning true or false based on whether there were any. This is especially useful if you need to pass the glob pattern from a variable/script argument.

```bash
glob_pattern='../smth*/*'
while read -r file; do
    # your thing
    echo "read $file"
done < <(compgen -G "$glob_pattern" || true)
```

adding the  `|| true` prevents a false return from `compgen` causing any problems. This method avoids issues with no matches and does not require changing nullglob options.

If you need the items in an array, just initialise one with `files=()` before the loop, and `files+=("$file")` inside the loop. You can then see if there were any matches by simply checking the length of the array with `if [[ ${#files[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then`.

Comment: I used to think this was a satisfactory solution, but it turned out not to be. For instance, `compgen` does not work properly for files with "composed extensions"; i.e. if you have a file `file.txt.bin`, with two extensions, expanding `**/*.bin` will weirdly not match them.
In my case I was trying to expand the glob in the context of a Git script. Luckily, `git ls-files "$glob"` works just as I'd expect. While not a general solution outside of Git trees, I thought I might as well point it out here.

Comment: @resolritter I just ran `compgen -G '/**/*.gz'` (on bash v4.2.46) and it found several files with composed extensions. I also have the shell option `globstar` `off`. Are you saying `compgen -G '**/*.bin'` produces no output where `echo **/*.bin` does?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to use a standard input (pipe) in case a resulting command exceeds a command line length limit. The following command worked for me:

```
echo "../smth*/*" "/etc/cron*/" | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -O nullglob -c "echo {}" | xargs -n1
```

or for a list of globs:

```
cat huge_glob_list.txt | xargs -n1 -I{} bash -O nullglob -c "echo {}" | xargs -n1
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to overcomplicate things:

```bsh
echo your/stuff*
```

Comment: this doesn't work. For example: `TEST=$(echo your/stuff*) && eval \"$TEST\"` will output: `your/stuff*: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Sebastian this is a nullglob issue, see above

Comment: No, it's not a nullglob issue. Using scape characters is evaluating `TEST` variable as a string including `*` and not being expanded.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have the same question. And I find that the solution is very simple:  (and it is POSIX compliant.)

- Set `$IFS` to empty string, which disable word splitting by whitespace characters.
- Then just unquote the variable to let it expands the globs.

Example code illustrated in **for-loop**:

```
pattern='some * dir/my file *'

unset old_IFS ; [ -n "${IFS+x}" ] && old_IFS=${IFS} ; IFS=''
IFS=''

for f in ${pattern} ; do
    IFS=${old_IFS} ; [ -z "${old_IFS+x}" ] && unset IFS
    
    printf 'Filenames: %s \n' "${f}"
done
```

Please note that I do not set nullglob by `shopt -s nullglob` as `shopt` is not defined in POSIX. If the glob pattern is not found, the pattern expands to itself. `Filenames: some dir/my file *` is printed in the above code. It is easy to add an `if [ -e "${f}" ]; then ...` check if necessary.

The same approach can be used to set the **positional parameters** also.

```
pattern='some * dir/my file *'

unset old_IFS ; [ -n "${IFS+x}" ] && old_IFS=${IFS} ; IFS=''
set -- ${pattern}
IFS=${old_IFS} ; [ -z "${old_IFS+x}" ] && unset IFS
unset old_IFS

printf '[%s]\n' "$@"
```

Note that we cannot make it into one-liner `IFS='' command set -- ${pattern}`. This one-liner does not disable word splitting.

It may be used in **function parameters**, but it is not recommended. The restore of `$IFS` has to be located at the first statement of the function, which is not symmetric in style and easily be forgotten.

```
func() {
    IFS=${old_IFS} ; [ -z "${old_IFS+x}" ] && unset IFS
    unset old_IFS
    printf '[%s]\n' "$@"
}

pattern='some * dir/my file *'

unset old_IFS ; [ -n "${IFS+x}" ] && old_IFS=${IFS} ; IFS=''
func $pattern
```

Personally I would prefer passing `$pattern` into the function, then `set -- $pattern` inside the function. But it is not always possible if the function carries other positional parameters also.

```
func() {
    unset old_IFS ; [ -n "${IFS+x}" ] && old_IFS=${IFS} ; IFS=''
    set -- ${pattern}
    IFS=${old_IFS} ; [ -z "${old_IFS+x}" ] && unset IFS
    unset old_IFS

    printf '[%s]\n' "$@"
}

pattern='some * dir/my file *'

func $pattern
```

This approach works for both the pattern and the filepaths:

- if they contain whitespace characters, indeed all characters, and
- if they contain glob characters, use escape `\*` to match a literal `*`, and
- when the glob characters locates in the directory path components and/or in the filename components. (If glob in directory path is necessary, it cannot be easily implemented using `find`.)

Comment: `[ -e "${f}" ]` fails for a file that is a symlink to an inaccessible file. `[ -e "$f" ] || [ -L "$f" ]` is better, but note that to expand `dir/*` glob, you only need to be able to read `dir` while for `[ -e dir/file ]` you need search access to the directory.

Comment: Beware `IFS=${old_IFS}` doesn't restore `$IFS` properly is `$IFS` was previously unset (an unset `IFS` doesn't mean the same thing as a `IFS` set to the empty   string)

Comment: See [Avoiding errors due to unexpanded asterisk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56087) for a common technique to work around the misfeature introduced by the Bourne shell (and reverted by several modern shells including zsh and fish) whereby a non-matching glob expands to itself. See also [Why is nullglob not default?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/204803)

Comment: Using `var='foo[*]bar*.txt'` is slightly more portable than`var='foo\*bar*.txt'` to escape `*` even if both are meant to be POSIX.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - Thank you for heads up. I will be careful with symlinks, and when dir with no `r` or with no `x`. In most cases. dir with only `x` then read the file, is more applicable than dir with only `r` and we can only list the files but nothing else can be done. So I think a check of `[ -e dir/file ]` serves most scenarios.

Comment: I know `unset IFS` means `IFS=<space><tab><newline>` while `IFS=''` means split on nothing. But the code above did not unset IFS previously.

Comment: May I know the reason why `var='foo[*]bar*.txt'` is more portable? Is it because matched literal `[*]` results into `*`, on the other hand, matched literal `\*` results into `\*`? Just like replacing `[*]` with `\*` does not work in the code here - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56087/150246 .

Comment: Depending on the shell implementation, `var='foo\*bar*.txt' sh -c 'IFS=; echo $var'` matches either on `foo*barWHATEVER.txt` or `foo\WHATEVERbarWHATEVER.txt` (like in Ubuntu 20.04's mksh), while `var='foo[*]bar*.txt'` matches the former consistently across shells.

Comment: I meant that that code doesn't restore `$IFS` properly if called in a context where `$IFS` was unset. See also [What's a safe and portable way to split a string in shell programming?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/64160)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - Regarding `[*]` is more preferable than `\*`, I am just facing this problem. You spotted it before I notice. I got this question in Bash: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/767124/backslash-in-unquoted-variable-for-glob-expansion . And I notice in your example, if there is no second asterisk, the first asterisk will become literal.  **This is weird.** `var='foo\*bar.txt' sh -c 'IFS=; ls $var'` matches only the file `foo\*bar.txt` literally.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - The issue of **if `$IFS` was previously unset** is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays most linux distributions have `python` included, so you can just run the following command in shell

```bash
python -c 'from glob import glob; print(glob("*"))'
```

You are free modify the `python` script to meet your requirement, for example, dump to json format string.

```bash
python -c 'from glob import glob; from json import dumps; print(dumps(glob("*")))'
```