# Avoiding errors due to unexpanded asterisk

Tags: bash, wildcards, for

In bash I often use for-loops such as the following

```
for file in *.type; do 
  sommecommand "$file"; 
done;
```

to perform an operation for all files matching `*.type`. If no file with this ending is found in the working directories the asterisk is not expanded and usually I will get an error message saying that somecommand didn't find the file. I can immediately think of several ways to avoid this error. But adding a conditional does not seem to be very elegant. Is there a short and clean way to achieve this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes, run the following command :

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

it will nullify the match and no error will be triggered.

- if you want this behaviour by default, add the command in your `~/.bashrc`
- if you want to detect a null glob in POSIX shell, try

  ```
  for i in *.txt; do
    [ "$i" = '*.txt' ] && [ ! -e '*.txt' ] && continue
  done
  ```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/NullGlob

Comment: Note that it is actually possible to have a file called `*.txt`. It would be worth checking if the file exists.

Comment: post edited accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisDown Note that the same comment as on your answer applies here (with potentially more severe consequences because of the `break` instead of `continue`).

Answer (score 9):

In bash you can use `shopt -s nullglob` to expand to an empty array if there are no matches.

In POSIX shells without `nullglob`, you can avoid this problem by checking that the filename being passed actually exists by having `[ -e "$file" ] || [ -L "$file" ] || continue` as the first part of your `for` loop.

Comment: Note that it wouldn't be strictly equivalent since `[ -e` would return false for inaccessible files or files that are symlinks to inaccessible or unexisting files.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, let the points about symlinks be acknowledged. But what do you have in mind by "inaccessible files"? Even if I `chmod 0 the_file`, `[ -e the_file ]` still evaluates true, so it must be something else.

Comment: submitted edit to handle broken symlinks. hope that's ok.

Comment: @dubiousjim, `mkdir -p x/{a,b} && chmod 444 x && echo x/* && [ -e x/a ]`. x/a is inaccessible but as x is  readable x/* will expand.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, great, thanks for explaining.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas in that case, how would you `test` to see if there exists an inaccessible file?

Comment: @ban_javascript, my  answer shows a POSIX way to list directory entries. The ones in there for which `[ -e file ]` (initially, that was `[ -a file ]` for accessible) returns false would be the entries that exist but which you can't `stat()`. The error code returned by `stat()` / `lstat()` can sometimes tell you that a file truely doesn't exist when you try to find out. More details at [How do I tell if a file does not exist in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40046642)

Answer (score 8):

The usual technique for shells that don't have a `nullglob` option is

```
set -- [*].type *.type
case $1$2 in
  '[*].type*.type') shift 2;;
  *) shift
esac
for file do
  cmd  -- "$file"
done
```

The extra `[*].type` is to cover the case where there's one file called `*.type` in the current directory.

Now, if you want to include dot files, [that becomes more complicated](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.unix.shell/msg/77ee56c75fc23e23?hl=en).

I beleive that technique was coined by Laura Fairhead on usenet a few years ago.

Comment: Nice solution. I think adding this explanation helps me to understand. Case 1 of 3) No file matches. `[*].type *.type` results into `[*].type*.type` literally. `shift 2` to discard them. Case 2 of 3) File `*.type` does not exist. `[*].type` is not matched, thus results in `[*].type` literally. `shift 1` to discard `$1`. Case 3 of 3) File `*.type` exists. `[*].type` expands to `*.type`. `*.type*.type` does not fall into the `case` with `shift 2`. `shift 1` to discard `$1` which is an extra match.

Comment: In my opinion, adding a conditional check is more straightforward, more robust, and works in more scenarios. For example, if the pattern is supplied from a variable, it is not straightforward to generate `[*].pattern` from `*.pattern`. The OP did not want a conditional check though.

Comment: @midnite, if by conditional check, you mean `[ -e "$file" ] || [ -L "$file" ]`, it needs access to the files (being able to `lstat()` them), while glob expansion only needs read access to the directory, so is not a valid way to check a directory entry exists (though it's often good enough).

Comment: I agree conditional check is doing a different thing than checking if a directory entry exists. I meant in most cases we concern about using (r or w or x) the file. If the directory entry exists but not usable, the script needs to handle this exception in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

`find . -name '*.type' -maxdepth 0 -exec somecommand "{}" ";"`

This removes the `for` loop and the shell's globbing from the equation entirely. `find` will execute the `-exec` command once per match, and if there are no matches, it will never be executed. The `-maxdepth 0` instructs find to not recurse into subdirectories of the named path-argument (`.`, in this case).

The downside is that it involves another application, albeit one that is present on virtually every Linux system out there (and probably most Unixes as well).