# using stat to provide timestamp for touch

Tags: bash, scripting, stat

Am trying to OCR some documents insitu (from a linux command line on a windows share).  The process of OCRing is find and I have muddled through using the find command to pipe the files through the loop correctly.

However I need to preserve the original timestamp for modified.  I am currently trying to use stat and touch as below:

```
#!/bin/bash
OLDIFS=$IFS

    IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")

    for f in `find /mnt/library/Libra/Libra/Ashfords -name "*.pdf"`
         do
        ORIGTS=`stat -c "%Y" $f`
        sudo /opt/ABBYYOCR9/abbyyocr9 -rl English -pi -if $f -f PDFA -paemImageOnText -pafpr original -of $f
        touch -t $ORIGTS $f

    done

    IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Of course the touch command fails.  running the commands separately I notice "stat -c" is something along the lines of this:

1334758696

which is like no date I know.  I feel as if I am close but cannot work out how to convert the date I have in to a touch friendly version.  Is it some form of seconds from something?

Comment: Aside: your use of `IFS` seems unusual.  Did you really want to split on backspace (`\b`)?  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names/9499#9499 for some tips.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`stat's` output is a Unix timestamp, also called *seconds since the Epoch*.

All GNU coreutils that accept a date allow you to put a timestamp instead by prefixing the timestamp with an `@`.

So try this

```
touch -d @$ORIGTS $f
```

See [coreutils - Seconds since the epoch](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Seconds-since-the-Epoch.html#Seconds-since-the-Epoch)

Comment: ah that explains a lot of timestamps i have seen in linux now!  Thanks alot

Answer (score 8):

`touch` can use a file's timestamp using the `-r` option. You might want to output to a different file (I assume below that `-if` is input file and `-of` is output file)

```
for f in ...; do
    sudo /opt/ABBYYOCR9/abbyyocr9 ... -if $f ... -of $f.new
    touch -r $f $f.new
    mv $f.new $f
done
```

Answer (score 3):

> `IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")`

Since you're assuming a shell with `echo -e`, and you have bash in your shebang line anyway, you can use `IFS=$'\n\b'`. Making backspace a separator is rather weird. You don't need `IFS` for what you're doing anyway.

> `OLDIFS=$IFS`
>   …
>   `IFS=$OLDIFS`

Note that this restores the old value of `IFS` only if `IFS` was initially set. If `IFS` was initially unset, this sets `IFS` to the empty string, which is completely different. In ksh, bash or zsh, if you need to set `IFS` temporarily, you can write your code in a function and make `IFS` local to this function. In other shells, you need to be careful about the unset case.

> `` `find /mnt/library/Libra/Libra/Ashfords -name "*.pdf"` ``

Never use command substitution on the output of `find`.

- This splits the output at the characters in `$IFS`. If you set `IFS` to a newline, then this splits the output at newlines, but you still can't handle file names containing newlines.
- Not only is the result of command substitution split into words, but then each word is used as a glob pattern. If you files called `A[12].pdf`, `A1.pdf` and `A2.pdf`, you'll end up with `A1.pdf A2.pdf A1.pdf A2.pdf`. You can turn globbing off with `set -f` (and back on with `set +f`), but here (like most of the time) the right way is not to use command substitution.

Use the `-exec` argument to `find` (or if your system has `-print0`, you can use `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …` instead; this is only useful to act on multiple files at once if you need portability to ancient Linux systems or current OpenBSD systems that have `-print0` but not `-exec … {} +`).

> ```
> ORIGTS=`stat -c "%Y" $f`
> # [transform $f]
> touch -t $ORIGTS $f
> ```

Note that you're missing double quotes around `$f` (they aren't needed if these are the results of splitting and you haven't changed `IFS` since then and globbing is turned off, but really, always put double quotes unless you know why you can't leave them on).

This is clumsy and non-portable (`stat` doesn't exist on all systems, and its arguments are different across the different systems where it exists). `touch` has a portable option to set a file to the timestamp of another file: `touch -r REFERENCE_FILE FILE`. I would recommend one of two approaches instead:

- If you can, first transform the original file into a new file, then call `touch -r` to set the date of the new file, and finally move the new file into place. It's better to make sure the output is fine before anything happens to the input; otherwise, if the transformation is interrupted for any reason (e.g. a power failure), you'll lose data.
- If the transformation is a black box that you have no control over, you can use `touch -r` twice: once to save the date of the original file on an empty temporary file (which will be automatically created), then again after the transformation to restore the date using the temporary file.

Thus:

```
find /mnt/library/Libra/Libra/Ashfords -name '*.pdf' \
     -exec sh -c 'transform "$0" to "$0.tmp" && touch -r "$0" "$0.tmp" && mv -f "$0.tmp" "$0"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I missed the answer about `touch -r`; if for some strange reason you neither have GNU coreutils’ `stat` as in the accepted answer nor can use `touch -r`, here's how to get the timestamp in `touch`-friendly format with a BSD-like `stat`.

```
% /usr/bin/stat -f '%Sm' johnson                   
Oct 23 22:51:00 2012
% /usr/bin/stat -t '%Y%m%d%H%M.%S' -f '%Sm' johnson
201210232251.00
% touch foo
% touch -t $(/usr/bin/stat -t '%Y%m%d%H%M.%S' -f '%Sm' johnson) foo
% /usr/bin/stat -f '%Sm' foo                    
Oct 23 22:51:00 2012
```

But really, just use `touch -r`:

```
% touch foo
% touch -r johnson foo
% /usr/bin/stat -f '%Sm' foo
Oct 23 22:51:00 2012
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, coming from the 'moviemaking' proces'.

In the example below `orig_file.wav` is the file with original timestamp, while `processed_file.wav` is the file with same contents, but wrong timestamp.

BEFORE:

`localhost $ ls -lh orig_file.wav processed_file.wav 
Jan 23 17:15 processed_file.wav
Jul  9  2018 orig_file.wav`

THE COMMAND:

`` localhost $ touch -t $(date --date=@`stat -f%B orig_file.wav` +%Y%m%d%H%M.%S) processed_file.wav ``

AFTER:

`localhost $ ls -lh orig_file.wav processed_file.wav 
Jul  9  2018 processed_file.wav
Jul  9  2018 orig_file.wav`

NOTES:

`stat` in inverted ticks gives you the creation timestamp of the original file as unix epoch time (in seconds). The @ from coreutils converts it to an iso date that `date` can understand and reformat with YYYYMMDDHHmm.SS so that `touch` can understand it. I put the `date` command into $(), as an equivalent of inverted ticks, as they cannot be reused in the same command.

Comment: (1) This seems to be almost exactly the same as [Nicholas Riley’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36763/80216#454061) but more complicated.  Why would anybody want to use this rather than that (or, better yet, [glenn jackman’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/36763/80216#36771), using `touch -r`)? (2) `stat` can be put in `$(…)`; they can be used multiple times in one command.

Comment: Other than his answer using the modification time rather than create time, you seem to be correct. I did not notice this other answer. You can down-vote mine.

Comment: Well, if you ask me to, it's no fun.    :-)    ⁠