# Count number of characters per listed filename

Tags: ls, wc

Given the following ls result:

```
$ ls
Desktop  Documents  Downloads  Music  Pictures  Public  Templates  Videos
```

This will give the total number of characters for all files:

```
$ ls | wc -m
67
```

But how can I have calculate the number of characters per file name? For the same file list the result I'm after would be something like this:

```
8
10
10
6
etc...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done in a very simple shell script:

```
for file in *; do echo -n "$file" | wc -m; done
```

Just loop through each file echoing the name to `wc`. The `-n` on the `echo` is so that it doesn't append a newline, which would erroneously increase the count by 1.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Also thanks for the `echo -n` tip. I had noticed the `wc` was counting one extra character but had not yet started dwelling on that one.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to call out to `wc`, bash is perfectly capable: `${#var}` is the length of the value of $var.

```
for f in *; do echo ${#f}; done
```

[reference](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Answer (score 1):

While [@Patrick's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109235/7453) is perfectly fine if you have to do a similar task over a directory tree's worth of files you'll need to change your tactics slightly. One method for handling this is to use `find` & `while`.

#### find & while

```
$ depth=2
$ find . -maxdepth $depth -type f -print0 | sed 's|\./||g' | \
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do \
      f=$(basename "$file"); printf "%s: %s\n" "$file" "${#f}"; \
    done | column -s : -t
dir2/more files3.txt        15
some long spacey file.txt   25
dir1/more files1.txt        15
dir1/more files2.txt        15
file 1.txt                  10
file 2.txt                  10
```

The above will generate a list of files separated by `\0` (i.e. NULLs). You can use the variable `$depth` to control how deep `find` will look. This list is then scrubbed so that any `.\` characters are removed via `sed`.

Lastly we loop through this list and use a `printf` to print each file's name out along with its length, using Bash's built-in facility to count the length of a string, `${#var}`. The `printf` will print the file + its path but only the size of the file.

The `column -s : -t` is just to pretty print it. It does so by splitting the output on the colon, `:`, and then splitting the output up into equidistant columns.

Comment: There's no whitespace problem in Patrick's answer, not even newlines. Since the variable is quoted, there's no issue with horizontal whitespace: `var=$'hello\nworld';echo -n "$var" | wc -m`
=> 11

Comment: @glennjackman - what am I missing then? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names. I know I've switched back and forth on this most annoying topic. I tried his code and you're correct BTW.

Comment: The difference is `for f in *` -- using the wild card avoids word splitting. The shell knows you're iterating over filenames. When you do `for f in $(...)` you're iterating over words in text output of some program.

Comment: @glennjackman - thanks, that's what I kind of figured but a bit more research and re-relearning it I now see the diff.

Comment: In more detail, I guess the wildcard is expanded into filenames, and those filenames are not subjected to a 2nd round of word-splitting expansion.

Comment: @glennjackman - it seems that the shell will expand the wildcard into atoms, those atoms are not subjected to any additional splitting and are viewed as split on where they matched an item to the glob. I don't know why but this still mixes me up all the time.

Comment: is it possible to modify the command to output a CSV file? One column with the path and file name and a second column with the character number?

Comment: @ECII sure that would be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Count you help me with it please?

Comment: @ECII - `find . -maxdepth $depth -type f -print0 | sed 's|\./||g' | \
    while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do \
      f=$(basename "$file"); printf "%s,%s\n" "$file" "${#f}"; \
    done `

Comment: @ECII - simply take out the `| column ..` at the end and change the `printf` to put a comma between things instead, `printf "%s,%s\n"`.