# For loop in Unix : including files from sub directories

Tags: for

A simple for loop in Unix would be:

```
for FILE in $BASE_WORK_DIR/*.pdf
   do
     echo $FILE
   done
```

This will echo all `.pdf` files inside BASE_WORK_DIR directory.

What if `BASE_WORK_DIR` contains sub directories as well which also contain the pdf file.

In that case how can I design my for loop to take all pdf files from `BASE_WORK_DIR` as well as sub directories of `BASE_WORK_DIR` ?

Comment: All the methods you should use are covered here: [Looping through files with spaces in the names?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names/).

Comment: The fact that this question is also answered there doesn't mean that it's the same question -- to the contrary, in fact. Leaving this open.

Answer (score 6):

In `bash4`, and following symlinks to directories is desirable, you can enable `globstar` and use `**`:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in "$base_work_dir"/**/*.pdf
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

Otherwise in an `sh` script, `find` is probably the best way:

```
IFS='
'
set -f
for file in $(find "$base_work_dir" -name *.pdf)
do
  echo "$file"
done
```

(add the `-L` option to `find` to follow symlinks like with `bash` globstar)

Note that you will have issues here if any filenames contain newlines.

Comment: Better use `ksh93 -o globstar` or `zsh` whose `**` don't have the symlink issue.

Comment: @Stephane why is the `set -f` necessary when the `*.pdf` is quoted?

Comment: In every shell but `zsh` globbing is performed upon command substitution, so for instance if there's a file called `*.pdf` in `$base_work_dir/foo`, all the PDFs in `foo` except `*.pdf` will be counted twice. Leaving a variable or command substitution unquoted is the _split+glob_ operator. If you don't want the _glob_ part, you need `set -f`.

Answer (score 6):

The standard and canonical and reliable syntax is:

```
find . -type f -name '*.pdf' -exec sh -c '
  for f do
    something with "$f"
  done' sh {} +
```

(note that it may run several `sh` invocation if the list of files is very big).

With `zsh`, the equivalent would be

```
for f (./**/*(.NDoN)) {
  something with "$f"
}
```

(`.` for `-type f`, `D` to include hidden files, `oN` to not bother sorting the list, `N` to not complain if there's no matching file), except that you wouldn't get error messages for the directories you don't have access to.

Comment: Surely the caveat of the `sh` version is that you cannot set variables in the main part of the script from inside the loop?

Comment: @Graeme, yes, though you could pass them back to the calling shell using `export -p`.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution with `find` that would solve the problem of newlines in file names:

```
find "$BASE_WORK_DIR" -name '*.pdf' -print0 |
  while IFS= read -d '' -r file;do
    # your magic here
  done
```

[*Caveat emptor*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/110402/for-loop-in-unix-including-files-from-sub-directories/110414?noredirect=1#comment170581_110414): this only works in Zsh and Bash.

`-print0` only works in a few `find` implementations like GNU `find`. Use `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` if your find doesn't support it.

Comment: The `$'\0'` and `-d` option for read will work in `bash` only.

Comment: Lol, that would have been an interesting one to debug further down the line.

Comment: @slm I did not know that. Thanks :).

Comment: @JosephR, `bash` doesn't support passing NUL characters in arguments (contrary to `zsh`), `$'\0'` **_is_** `''` in `bash`.