# How can I list files of which no symlinks exist?

Tags: command-line, files, find, symlink

I have a large "myfiles" directory full of miscellaneous documents and do not want to modify its structure.

I therefore created (several) other directories for each class of documents. For example, I have an "images" directory which has symlinks to each `.jpg` or `.cr2` file in the "myfiles" directory plus other descriptive files for each symlink (with the same filename) with description and other metadata. The symlinks in the /images directory might have a different name from the original linked file.

I am trying to find the simplest way to make sure each and every image file in the "myfiles" directory has a symlink into the "images" directory.

See an example of the folder structure

```
/myfiles/a.doc
/myfiles/b.jpg
/myfiles/c.cr2
/myfiles/d.mov
```

should result

```
/images/b_800x600.jpg
/images/b_800x600.desc
/images/c_3820x5640.cr2
/images/c_3820x5640.cr2
```

Comment: Not a full answer but you could save the results of a `find /myfiles -type f` to a file then use `find /images -type l -exec readlink {} \; | egrep myfiles` to get a list of files that are symlinked in `/images` then iterate over the results doing a `sed` on each one to delete the paths in the first file you save since they already have the symlink and the files left over are the files that _don't_ have the symlink.

Comment: Is it possible for you to use hardlinks instead, so you can use the hardlink counter to see if you have links? Using `ls -l` you can see the hardlink count in the second column.

Comment: Do what @Lambert says. `rm` those symlink dirs and use `pax -rwl -s "\|.*regex|modifes_filename|" /path/to/myfiles/*.jpg /path/to/jpg_dir` for example to get hardlinks with programmatically altered filenames for only those that files that match your jpgs. You can get a lot more than that out of it - like batching based on change times and etc.

Answer (score 6):

If I undersood the question correctly you need files in myfiles which do not have symlinks in images:

```
#!/bin/bash

OIFS="$IFS"
IFS=$'\n'

files="$(find myfiles/ -type f -name '*.jpg' -or -name '*.cr2')"
for f in $files; do
    list="$(find -L images/ -xtype l -samefile "$f")"
    if [[ "$list" == "" ]]; then
        echo "$f does not have symlink."
    fi
done

IFS="$OIFS"
```

There is a caveat with this approach if you have file a.jpg in directory myfiles/1 and you have a symlink to that file in directory images/3 or simply in images/ the file will not be reported with missing symlink.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes you did understand correctly. Close but not quite. My fault no yours :-) The example I gave shows a simplistic myfiles directory. In reality the image files under myfiles can be inside any arbitrary level of nested directories.

Comment: I edited the answer to search in entire myfiles, but check if this is what you desire.

Comment: ALMOST there :-) Your script hiccups when files have spaces (and maybe other crap such as single apostrophes" in them ...

Comment: I think now it should be ok

Comment: Your last modification splits every f at the occurence of every letter n ! :-) I cnahged the IFS line to IFS= then a newline from the keyboard then another ". Now the split seems to work but I get a long sequence of "missinglinks.sh: 11: missinglinks.sh: [[: not found"

Comment: As of this [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names) this is just to handle files with spaces - it works for me as expected. I'll check it again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22393/discussion-between-robert-alexander-and-taliezin).

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the files under `myfiles` are not symbolic links, and that none of the file names contain newlines. (My approach can still work if these assumptions are violated but it gets more complicated.) I also assume that you have the common `readlink` utility and that it supports `-f` to canonicalize paths, which is the case on Linux (both GNU and BusyBox), but not on e.g. OSX.

Build a list of files, and sort it for good measure:

```
find /myfiles -type f -print | sort >all.list
```

Build a list of symbolic link targets, with absolute paths.

```
find /images -type f -exec readlink -f {} \; | sort >linked.list
```

List the files that are not linked:

```
comm -32 all.list linked.list
```

If you use a shell that supports process substitution, you can put it all in one command:

```
comm -23 <(find /myfiles -type f -print | sort) \
         <(find /images -type f -exec readlink -f {} \; | sort)
```

If the links under `/images` are absolute, you can use `readlink` without the `-f` option, which is available under *BSD and OSX.

Comment: I was about to post something like your `comm` command but I won't now that I see you already did.  However, the redirect from `sort` make no sense; then the process substitutions will not output anything.  Also, you could add many directories next to `/images` if you want to find files in `/myfiles` which are not symlinked to from any of a number of directories besides `/images`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665/how-to-resolve-symbolic-links-in-a-shell-script for alternatives to `readlink -f`

Comment: @tripleee I forgot to take out the redirection when I built the process redirection version, thanks. Yes, you could add easily other directories or make other variations.