# lp add file-path to pdf

Tags: pdf, printing, pdftk

Is there an easy way how to add a filepath (or a string) to a printed pdf using `lp, convert, pdftk, python` or friends?

I want to print a bunch of pdf files with watermarks/headers which are parts of the file-path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a semi-easy solution using `pdftk, enscript, iconv, ps2pdf` in the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                       

IFS=$'\n'  # for files with spaces https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names                                                                                                                                                                                        
for pdf in $( ls */*.pdf ) ; do                                                                                                                                                       
   echo $pdf
   # create a watermark and handle encoding properly                                                                                                                                                                                       
   echo $pdf | iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ISO-8859-2 | enscript -o - | ps2pdf - stamp.pdf                                                                                                                
   pdftk $pdf background stamp.pdf output out.pdf                                                                                                                                                  
   rm stamp.pdf                                                                                                                                                                                    
   lp -d printer out.pdf                                                                                                                                                                      
   rm out.pdf                                                                                                                                                                                      
   echo ""                                                                                                                                                                                         
done
```

Any comments are welcome.