# How to match files that have spaces in their file naming format

Tags: shell-script, filenames

I have a file `test.txt` which contains file names like below where some file names will have spaces and some will not.

```
Mon - Tue corrected item.csv
Sat -Sun incorrect item.csv
Wed_THU_corrected_item.csv
```

Now I have a script where I have a `for` loop that is intended to find these files which are listed in `test.txt` at a particular "path" where files will come daily just to make sure files exist. So please let me know how I can match such files that have spaces in their name.

```
for file in `cat test.txt`
do
    if [ ! -f path/$file ];
    then action item
    fi
done
```

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: Related: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/80216)

Comment: Related: [Looping through files with spaces in the names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9496/80216)

Comment: @deepak: please review the suggested duplicates. We believe they address your problem already. In particular, always use quotes around your variables, just like this: `"$file"`. In any case, feel free to open new question on specific bash scripting topics on this site.

Answer (score 3):

Never use `cat` for loops! Use `while read...`:

```
while read -r file; do
    [ -f "path/$file" ] || echo "$file"
done < test.txt
```

Comment: can you explain the usage of done < test.txt  and also path is the place where file will come in very same format  which are contained in test.txt.Also when we use  while read -r file , do we have to mention which file while loop is going to read