# Bash script for writing metadata attributes of files into separate text files

Tags: linux, shell-script, osx, file-metadata

I tried to code a bash script that loops through a given directory and all its subdirectories and extracts metadata attributes with the `mdls` command into separate text files. Since I have a lot of filenames containing spaces and other special characters, my code base is derived from the answer "[Looping through files with spaces in the names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names)".
But after each file the script waits
for pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>/<kbd>Return</kbd> manually.

How can I make it automatically loop through files and folders?

```
#!/bin/bash
# write metadata of files in separate file

find . -type f -name '*.*' -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    echo "$file"
    mdls "$file" > "$file"_metadata.txt
    read line </dev/tty
  done
' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The `read line </dev/tty` command is reading a line from the terminal
   (i.e., the keyboard). 
   If you don’t want to do that, delete that command.
2. Does the loop seem to be working well aside from that? 
   (At a glance, it looks pretty much OK to me.) 
   If not, edit your question to say what happens.
3. `-name '*.*'` says to look only at files whose names contain a period
   (a.k.a. “dot”, **`.`**). 
   If you want to exclude files whose names *don’t* include a **`.`**
   (like `data` and `README`), then that’s the perfect way to do it. 
   But if you want to handle *all* files, leave off the `-name` clause —
   find looks at all files by default;
   clauses like `-type f`, `-name something`,
   `-mtime value`, etc.,
   all specify restrictions (i.e., exclusions) to the search.

Answer (score 1):

```
find /path/to/Users/myuser -type f -print0 | 
xargs -0 -I% sh -c "mdls "%" > "%"_metadata.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you. Your script has an issue with spaces in filenames and doesn't grab files recursively in subdirectories. But your answer gave me a hint and I updated my code and my question: now the problem is narrowed down.

Comment: This also has problems with files with shell syntax characters (such as quotes or wildcard characters) in their names. And you may believe that that’s unlikely to happen, but remember: single quote and apostrophe are the same character.  It’s somewhat common for filenames to contain apostrophes. As a general rule, it’s dangerous to insert a filename directly into a shell command.  It’s better to provide the filename as an argument and then reference it with `"$1"` (or something similar).

Comment: OK, that handles many of the bad cases. It still has problems if a filename contains *double* quote characters (**`"`**); i.e., the ones you added to your answer.