# Command not working properly in shell script

Tags: shell-script

Here is output of:

```
sudo iwlist scan 2>/dev/null | grep ESSID | sed 's/.*ESSID:"\(.*\)".*/\1/' 2>/dev/null
```

```
Yash Shah
CoreFragment
CoreFragment_5G
CoreFragment
dlink
Yash Shah
COMFAST
Appbirds_Technologies
SYMBIOSIS
20096641
CoreFragment_5G
AMBER_AP1
REDWING LABS_5G
```

While the same thing written in a script is not working the same.

Here is a snippet in which I used above command.

```
for ssid_name in $(sudo iwlist scan 2>/dev/null | grep ESSID | sed 's/.*ESSID:"\(.*\)".*/\1/' 2>/dev/null)
do
    echo "$ssid_name"
done
```

I got output like this:

```
Yash
Shah
CoreFragment
CoreFragment_5G
CoreFragment
Yash
Shah
REDWING
LABS
COMFAST
Appbirds_Technologies
SYMBIOSIS
CoreFragment_5G
REDWING
LABS_5G
```

**Note**: When there is a space in output it take as a new line.

I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Not a duplicate, but the whitespace problem is discussed here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9496/173368

Comment: i didn't find that (might be due to word match) so I created question

Comment: No problem. I wanted to link to that QA because it contains several comprehensive answers that go into the details of that problem.

Comment: yaa...  it's really useful link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, note that it is not *one* command behaving differently. In your code snippets, standard output is written by two quite different commands.
Your first one prints `sed`'s output, while in your second one:

1. The output of `sed` is substituted (by the command substitution `$(...)`) after `in`;
2. The resulting string is expanded into a list of elements;
3. Each item is in turn assigned to `ssid_name` and printed by `echo`.

Expansion in point 2 is performed according to the value of the internal field separator (`IFS`), which by default is `<space><tab><newline>`. Thus, [your solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494756/315749) works because it lets `for` split the substituted string on newlines only.

As an aside on your answer, note that `$'\n'` is not portable - even if that syntax (`$'string'`) is supported in many shells.
You can nevertheless use an assignment like this:

```sh
IFS='
'
```

An alternative construct for processing lines of input is using `read` in a `while` loop:

```sh
sudo iwlist scan 2>/dev/null | grep ESSID | sed 's/.*ESSID:"\(.*\)".*/\1/' 2>/dev/null |
while IFS= read -r i; do
    printf '%s\n' "$i"
done
```

Here, too, each line of `sed`'s output is split according to the value of `IFS` - that in this example is set to the null string exactly to prevent any effects of word splitting - but lines would be kept separated by `read` regardless of `IFS`.

Answer (score 3):

Better use a `while` loop with `read` instead of a `for` loop.

```
sudo iwlist scan 2>/dev/null |grep ESSID | sed 's/.*ESSID:"\(.*\)".*/\1/' 2>/dev/null | while IFS= read -r ssid_name
do
    echo $ssid_name
done
```

see also https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Answer (score 1):

By adding following line in code before for loop, work perfactly in my case.

```
IFS=$'\n'
```