# Why doesn't $() expand properly?

Tags: bash, find, quoting

I want to play all the .mp3 files within a directory using vlc, so I do something like this:

```
vlc $(find ~/Documents/music -name "*.mp3" -exec "echo \"{}\"" \;)
```

The issue is that I get "vlc: unknown option or missing mandatory argument `-D'". Presumably a parsing issue.

So let's do it file by file:

```
echo $(echo $(find ~/Documents/music -name "*.mp3" -exec echo "\"{}\" \n " \;) | head -n 1)
```

I get:

```
"/home/XXX/Documents/music/My Folder/1 - track/the name of track.mp3"
```

And when I run:

```
vlc "/home/XXX/Documents/music/My Folder/1 - track/the name of track.mp3"
```

It works.

But when I run

```
vlc $(echo $(find ~/Documents/music -name "*.mp3" -exec echo "\"{}\" \n " \;) | head -n 1)
```

I get:

```
cannot open file /home/XXX/the (No such file or directory)
```

Which would make sense if the arguments to vlc weren't properly quoted. But they are? So why is it being passed into vlc as an unquoted string?

Comment: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/73093)

Comment: [Looping through files with spaces in the names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9496/73093)

Comment: The echo command is within quotations in the first example vlc $(find ~/Documents/music -name "*.mp3" -exec "echo \"{}\"" \;) Could that perhaps be the issue?

Comment: See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quotes are not processed in the output of expansions. If you do `$(echo '"foo bar"')`, or `$(echo "\"foo bar\"")`, what ends up as the argument to the main command is `"foo` and `bar"`. With literal quotes, and as two distinct arguments due to [word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting).

By default, word splitting happens on any whitespace, spaces or newlines, so from the output of `find`, you can't tell apart which whitespace is part of a filename, and which is part of what `find` printed to separate them. Even in general, you can't tell them apart, since file names can also contain newlines...

What you can do is:

```
find ... -print0 | xargs -0 vlc
```

or

```
find ... -exec vlc {} +
```

The first has `find` output the file names separated with NUL bytes, and tells `xargs` to expect just that. Not all systems have `find -print0` and `xargs -0`, though.

The second has `find` itself launch `vlc`, the trailing `{} +` tells it to pass multiple filenames to one invocation of `vlc`.

If you have a very large number of files to be found, and they don't fit on one command line, then both of those could launch `vlc` more than once.

See:

- [Word splitting](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting) on Greg's wiki
- The question [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373), which has a number of related situations.

Using `echo` to debug this doesn't really work as it will join its arguments with a single space, making it impossible to tell the difference between `echo foo bar`, and `echo "foo bar"`.

Answer (score 2):

The `$()` expands properly, but the shell does more to the result than what you are aware of.  Additionally, adding literal quotes to pathnames is almost never the correct thing to do (unless you are using `eval` somewhere).

To play all the MP3 files in or under `~/Documents/music` using `vlc`:

```
find ~/Documents/music -type f -name '*.mp3' -exec vlc {} +
```

This would run `vlc` with as many MP3 files as possible at a time.

To skip using `find` all-together:

```bash
shopt -s globstar
vlc ~/Documents/music/**/*.mp3
```

This would work as long as you don't have a massive amount of MP3 files (in which case you would get an error because the argument list became too long).

The `**` glob matches "recursively" down into a file hierarchy, but must be enabled with `shopt -s globstar` in `bash` (the `zsh` shell has this glob enabled by default).

---

Your command

```
vlc $(echo $(find ~/Documents/music -name "*.mp3" -exec echo "\"{}\" \n " \;) | head -n 1)
```

would first execute the `find`, `head` and `echo`.  That pipeline would output

```
"/home/XXX/Documents/music/My Folder/1 - track/the name of track.mp3"
```

The shell would then split that string into the words `"/home/XXX/Documents/music/My`, `Folder/1`, `-`, `track/the`, `name`, `of`, and `track.mp3"` on the spaces in the string.

`vlc` would then be called with those *separate* arguments. In particular, the `-` argument may be mistaken for an option while the others would most likely be taken as separate pathname operands.

This is explained in depth in

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/73093)
- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)