# Can't loop files using pwd if current directory has spaces in the path

Tags: bash, pwd

I have the following bit of code in a bash script I've created. When I run it from a directory with no spaces in the path it works as expected, however if I run from a directory with spaces it fails. I'm pretty sure I need to escape it somehow, but nothing I've tried seems to work.

```
for file in `pwd`/*
do 
    echo file:$file
done
```

By 'fails' I mean that if I run the command from the path "~/dir 1/ test" it would echo the following:

```
file: ~/dir
file: 1/
file: test
```

I'd expect it to list the files in the directory (which it does if there's no spaces in the current directory):

```
file: file 1
file: file 2
file: file 3
```

Note this is only an issue if the current directory has spaces in, files with spaces in are processed fine.

I've read several similar examples on here such as [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters) and [Looping through files with spaces in the names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names) but I can't see how (if they are relevant) they apply to my specific example.

Comment: what does `it fails` mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looping through files with spaces in the names?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9496/looping-through-files-with-spaces-in-the-names)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)

Comment: @jsotola I've edit the question so the formatting works

Comment: kaylum & Paulo Tomé I've read both of those, and if they do apply I don't understand how to apply them to the specific example above

Comment: put that info into the question above  .... questions should have the following format `this is what i am trying to do ... this is what i expect to happen ... this is what actually happens .... this is my question`

Comment: the link provided by @PauloTomé says to use double quotes around variables ... try `echo file:"$file"`

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't work. I believe the problem is with the line containing "for file in `pwd`/* as the array that line generates is what is at fault

Comment: Suggestion: `for file in "$(pwd)"/* do echo file:"$file" done`

Comment: @paull Tomé Thanks that was the answer

Comment: Suggestion: Use a linter to check your scripts, for instance: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Paulo Tomé I needed to change it to the following:

```
for file in "$(pwd)"/* 
do 
    echo file:"$file" 
done
```